# Removing a duplicate phrase

Tags: c#

I'm looking to remove duplicate phrases from any give string.

Example:

```
My_First_Post_My_First_Post.htm
```

Would have the phrase "My_First_Post" in there twice, thus becoming:

```
My_First_Post_.htm
```

Any easy way to do this?

Comment: How long does a substring have to be in order to be considered a phrase?  For instance, would "Hello world" collapse down to "Helo world"?

Comment: @Adam Yeah I'm definitely planning to implement a minimum. I'm guessing 10 consecutive characters would do.

Comment: What is the maximum distance between phrases? If somebody has "Hello World [100 chars] Hello World", does it condense into "Hello World [100 chars] "?

Comment: @arxanas Max distance would be two characters. One would still count.

Comment: Why is this question rated -2? It seems like a valid question to me.

Comment: @arxanas Yeah I'm scratching my head over here too.. oh well, at least I got an answer ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try regular expressions - careful about efficiency for sure, though:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<m>(.+))(.*?)\k<m>", RegexOptions.Compiled);
string str = "My_First_Post_My_First_Post.htm";

re.Replace(str, "$1$2"); // My_First_Post_.htm
```

It removes the first, longest, repeated sequence. To make it at least 10 characters, e.g., change the first group to:

```
(?<m>(.{10,}))
```

To restrict the distance between characters to 2, e.g., change the second group to:

```
(.{,2}?)
```

For 1 character, just put `(.??)`.

Comment: Can you explain what it is trying to do?

Comment: @L.B: It replaces the longest repeated sequence with only one instance of the repeated sequence.

Comment: Is there any way to alter this so that the max distance between the phrases would be one character? So if there's, as an example, "hi" in between the identical phrases, it would not remove anything. I'm not sure if it already does.. regex makes my head hurt.

Comment: @minitech Thanks! Did you test your code by the way? On my end `str` is still `My_First_Post_My_First_Post.htm` after the regex replace.

Comment: @natli: Sorry, I should have been more clear. The last method call *returns* the string; it doesn't change the string in place. So use `str = re.Replace(...);` instead.

Comment: @minitech My bad, really. I should know that stuff by now.. it's working fine, thanks much! It was worth the minus-rep on my question (heh), very useful stuff! ;)